# Duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 after installing AppDynamics pod

Tags: swift, cocoapods, static-libraries, appdynamics, xcode11.3

I'm using Xcode 11.3, my app is in Swift. When I add AppDynamics pod to my project and try to build, I get "1222 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64" error. All duplicates are in several .a static libraries that are unrelated to AppDynamics and that are all linked in "Link Binary With Libraries" in Build Phases (there are other .framework-s here too but they don't cause any issue). I tried all the standard things like cleaning build folder, deleting derived data, restarting computer, building with Xcode 11.2 version, playing with -ObjC flag, but none of this helped. Since there are so many duplicates, changing those static libraries is not an option as it has been suggested in some threads. Project also has other pods added that all worked fine.

[image]

I see that there were other similar questions, but I could not find an answer that worked in my case, I've been stuck on this for more than a day already. Does anyone have some other suggestion what I could try? I would like to understand why this is happening?

Comment: https://www.appdynamics.com/blog/product/getting-started-with-ios-using-swift-and-appdynamics/

Comment: I tried this too - adding it manually, but if I add the -ObjC linker flag as they state it needs, I get the same error again. If I remove -ObjC, it compiles, but then it crashes when initializing ADEumInstrumentation.

Comment: Any news on how to fix it? I'm having the same problem.